# How to generate random uniform distribution by selecting h/l values from multiple arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
max = [1, 5, 4]
min = [0, 1, 1]
 
        [[0.9, 4,  3.2 ]
final = [.    .    .  ]
        [0.1, 1.4, 1.4]]
```

I want to generate uniform distribution of n numbers using np.random,uniform() by taking each number in min/max as highest and lowest values and getting **final** np.array().

Comment: Is it intentional that some `min` values are larger than the corresponding `max` values?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake! max has to be larger than min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much detail in your question but I believe something like this is what you are looking for, I will produce 10 arrays sampled from the distribution with parameters given:

```
import numpy as np

max = [1, 5, 4]
min = [0, 1, 1]
 
results = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    for n_min, n_max in zip(min, max):
        results.append([np.random.uniform(n_min, n_max, size=3)])
```